# Why does content View height less than UITableViewCell height?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I select UITableViewCell with also create xib file.

When I create custom tableViewCell with xib, I see contentView height is 0,5 point less than tableViewCell height.

How do I make the contentView height same to cell height?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 0.5 is to account for the separator automatically applied to cell in a uitableview.