# ContentView height is equal to cell height when creating custom cell programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview

ContentView height is always 0,5 point less than cell height when creating custom cell with xib. I don't know why it is. I think it is a problem.

I wonder it is the same when creating custom cell with programmatically?

[image]

fieldStyle1 height 272, contentView height 271.5

Comment: Does this maybe have to do with the separator?

Comment: I don't think it is about sperator. I tried that table view adds separator out of container (cell).

Comment: Can you show some more of your code / XIB, how you set up constraints and so on?

Comment: You see it's height become automatically 271.5

Comment: you already asked this question, just a day ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086752/why-does-content-view-height-less-than-uitableviewcell-height why do you do this?

Comment: I dont't get an good answer.

Comment: You already got good (and correct) answers. Except of that you won't get a better answer creating multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already guessed this **has** to do with the `tableView`'s separator. Setting

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine / .none
```

in `viewDidLoad` and printing out `frame.height` for the `cell` / `contentView` in `willDisplayCell`

```
print(cell.frame.height)
print(cell.contentView.frame.height)
```

results in **77.0 / 76.5** for `.singleLine` and **76.5 / 76.5** for `.none`.

It might be that the heights differ in IB when using XIBs. But as you can see at runtime everything works as expected.

Comment: yes it become 76,5 and 76,5 . I set my cell height 272, and than seperator none. ıt becomes 272/271.5. I see 0,5 point with another background color when set cell backgroundcolor.

Comment: As I said: Just in IB when using XIBs. Run your app and check it in simulator / on device.

Comment: I run it in simulator. I want 77/77

Comment: If you use the built in separator you will always have that small difference. Create your own custom separator if the equality is that important.

Comment: Even If I do this full programmatically, it still has small difference? I mean contentview still be smaller?

Comment: Everything is said. You have that difference when using the built in separator. Except of that as @Milan Nosáľ stated you should not ask the same question multiple times.